# Laplace equation with periodic boundary conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Suppose I had the problem

$$\nabla^2 u(x,y) = 0 \text{ in } \Omega=[0,1]^2$$
with the periodic boundary condition:
$u(0,y)=u(1,y)$ and $u(x,0)=u(x,1)$

Note that I'm purposefully omitting periodic neumann conditions.

I'm pretty sure that this problem does not produce a unique solution (please correct me if I'm wrong!).  But can I say that the family of solutions to this problem is unique up to a constant factor.  That is, if $u_1$ and $u_2$ are solutions, can I say that $u_2=u_1+C$ for some real $C$?

Comment: Do you know the method of [separation of variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables#Partial_differential_equations)?

Comment: @Landscape: Of course!

Comment: Then applying this method you may find that the space of solutions is infinite dimensional.

Comment: @Landscape: Indeed, this is what I suspected.  But what of the form of the solutions?  Are *all* solutions scalar shifts of each other if the periodic neumann condition is not imposed?

Comment: @Paul:see here  http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~wjs/MTH5102/laplace10.pdf

Comment: I am afraid I cannot help you much more with this, but I suggest that you apply the method of separation of variables to find some explicit solutions first.

Comment: @Landscape: Sounds fair enough :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I remember answering a similar question not long ago: [Constants in Laplace's equation for a cube](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/403571/constants-in-laplaces-equation-for-a-cube/404243).

Let's make the problem more structure-revealing by scaling $\Omega$ to $[0,\pi]^2$.  Without considering any boundary condition, using separation of variables: $u(x,y) = X(x)Y(y)$ leads you to:
$$
X'' - \lambda X = 0,\quad\text{and}\quad Y'' + \lambda Y = 0.\tag{1}
$$
If $\lambda = \omega^2 >0$ (could be the other way, or $0$ but that is the trivial case where solution is spanned by $\{1,x,y,xy\}$ and you can't have periodic boundary conditions), then solving (1) leads to
$$
u(x,y) = \sum_{\omega\in A} c_{\omega}(a_1 e^{-\omega x} + a_2 e^{\omega x})\big(b_1 \cos (\omega y) + b_2  \sin (\omega y)\big), \tag{2}
$$ 
Let's restrict $A$ as $\mathbb{N}$ for now if this choice can generate all functions in the solution space we need. Now onto boundary condition, basically we want to use the boundary condition to pin down $a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2$ (they depend on $\omega$ as well), and $c_{\omega}$:
$$
u(x,0) = u(x,\pi),\quad\text{and}\quad u(0,y) = u(\pi,y).
$$
First one gives:
$$
\sum_{\omega\in A} c_{\omega}(a_1 e^{-\omega x} + a_2 e^{\omega x}) b_1 = -\sum_{\omega\in A} c_{\omega}(a_1 e^{-\omega x} + a_2 e^{\omega x}) b_1,
$$
which drives $b_1 = 0$. The second one gives:
$$\sum_{\omega\in A} c_{\omega}(a_1 + a_2 )b_2  \sin (\omega y) = \sum_{\omega\in A} c_{\omega}(a_1 e^{-\omega \pi} + a_2 e^{\omega \pi})b_2  \sin (\omega y).$$
This is where things get rather vague, if you just define $u(0,y) = u(\pi,y)$, not that they both equal to some specific function, we can't find all those coefficients.

---

Now onto answering your question, we can't say the family of solutions to this problem is unique up to a constant, for we have two families of solution! Other than (2), we can set $\lambda = -\omega^2<0$ and get the other familiy:
$$
u(x,y) = \sum_{\omega\in A} c_{\omega}\big(a_1 \cos (\omega x) + a_2  \sin (\omega x)\big)(b_1 e^{-\omega y} + b_2 e^{\omega y}), \tag{3}
$$
where family (2) corresponds to boundary condition $u(x,0) = u(x,\pi) = 0$, and family (3) corresponds to boundary condition $u(0,y) = u(\pi,y) = 0$.

Solution in family (3) can't be a constant plus a solution in family (2). Just think a plane sinusoidal wave traveling along $x$-axis, adding a constant is shifting up or down, we can't make it a plane sinusoidal wave traveling along $y$-axis.

And even for solution in the same family we can't do that! Think of the infinite superposition of different frequency of sinusoidal waves along one same direction: say we set $u(x,0) = u(x,\pi) = 0$, $u(0,y) = u(\pi,y) = g(y)$, and absorb $c$ into $a_1$ and $a_2$:
$$
u(x,y) = \sum_{\omega\in A} (a_1 e^{-\omega x} + a_2 e^{\omega x}) \sin (\omega y),\tag{$\dagger$}
$$
the second boundary condition leads to:
$$
\sum_{\omega\in A} (a_1 + a_2 ) \sin (\omega y) = \sum_{\omega\in A} (a_1 e^{-\omega \pi} + a_2 e^{\omega \pi}) \sin (\omega y) = g(y),
$$
for permissible $g$ whose Fourier expansion only has sine terms. Multiplying above for a specific frequency $\sin (\omega_0 y)$ and integrating on $[0,\pi]$ gives:
$$
\int^{\pi}_0 g(y)\sin (\omega_0 y) \,dy=\int^{\pi}_0  (a_1 + a_2 ) \sin^2 (\omega_0 y) \,dy= \int^{\pi}_0 (a_1 e^{-\omega_0\pi} + a_2 e^{\omega_0 \pi}) \sin^2 (\omega_0 y)\,dy,
$$
which is:
$$
\int^{\pi}_0 g(y)\sin (\omega_0 y) \,dy = \frac{\pi}{2} (a_1 + a_2 ) = \frac{\pi}{2}  (a_1 e^{-\omega_0\pi} + a_2 e^{\omega_0\pi}).
$$
Solving above yields:
$$
\begin{gathered}
a_1 = \frac{2(e^{\omega_0\pi}-1)}{\pi(e^{\omega_0\pi} - e^{-\omega_0\pi})}\int^{\pi}_0 g(y)\sin (\omega_0 y) \,dy,
\\
a_2 = \frac{2(1-e^{-\omega_0\pi})}{\pi(e^{\omega_0\pi} - e^{-\omega_0\pi})}\int^{\pi}_0 g(y)\sin (\omega_0 y) \,dy.
\end{gathered}\tag{$\ddagger$}
$$
We can see by this coefficient relation, if we add another permissible $h(y)$ to $g(y)$, it won't produce a solution adding a constant. Some coefficients, different for each frequency $\omega_0$, are added to the original coefficients of the $ (a_1 e^{-\omega x} + a_2 e^{\omega x})$ based on $g(y)$. Really this does not differ from the solution based on boundary condition $g(y)$ by a constant.

**Last remark**: even if we just add another *constant* to $g(y)$, we can't say the new solution only differs from the old solution by a constant.

A simple example is that if firstly we have $u(x,0) = u(x,\pi) = 0$, and $u(0,y) = u(\pi,y) = 1$, we have a solution $u_1(x,y)$, then we add 1 to the boundary condition $u(0,y) = u(\pi,y) = 1$, by $(\dagger)$ and $(\ddagger)$, the solution $u_2(x,y) = 2u_1(x,y)$, doubling the amplitude rather than differing by a constant.

If we add a constant to both boundary conditions, I believe we get a shift up or down, i.e., $u_2 = u_1 +C$.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer to the original question is definitely yes. The solution of this PDE is just a **constant** and you can add any other constant to it and this makes the whole space of admissible solutions.

I think my answer does not agree completely with what Shuhao said. I suppose that considering the symmetry of the solution (see that there is no difference between x and y neither in PDE nor for boundary conditions) the only possible $\lambda$ is zero which furnishes constant solutions as I claimed. Positive or negative $\lambda$ does not work since they do not make symmetric solutions.